# Assigning Material with texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AYC69tt-KMI) to create a soccer ball. 
Now I want to texture it in a way that every pentagon has an image inside itself and the exagons are white, but I also want everything to be a little glossy.
I managed to successfully UV Map the ball and paint the texture in photoshop but now I am having big problems in applying the texture material to the mesh.

[image: UV MAP]

I've created a new material in Blender Render mode with Diffuse and the texture applied to it. I also set the Texture mapping to UV. I've gone in edit mode, selected all the mesh and applied the material. Unfortunately in Texture View Mode I see just a white ball and while rendering I see everything's black.

[image: Ball seen in Edit Mode, Texture View, Blender Renders engine]

[image: Ball seen in Object Mode, Render View, Blender Renders engine]

If I try to do this in Cycles Render and use a Mix Shader with the FAC set to the texture image I get what I want in the Texture View Mode but while rendering I just see everything black and white of my colored images.

[image: Cycle Render Material Node]

[image: Cycle Render Texture View]

[image: Cycle Renders Render View]

I hope I've been clear enough and that someone will help me in this easy/difficult task!
Thank you in advance

Comment: What does lowpolyball.tif look like? I think that's the origin of the problem.

Comment: Here it is ![Exported in JPG](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4064417/hosted_images/lowpoly_ball.jpg)

Comment: Try putting the texture colour output into the diffuse BSDF colour input.

Comment: /me to late.. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## For cycles

Put your image texture in to a `Diffuse` node. Then use the factor in the `mix` node to determine how much gloss there is. The color on the `glossy` node should be nearly white, you don't need to plug the image texture in to it also.

[image: nodes]

Comment: So simple an so right! Thank you very much it worked.